# Hoverover Menu Select not working in IE

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium, menu, menuitem

I am using the below function to Hover-over a menu and select a child item. It is working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but does not seems to work in IE. In IE WebDriver can locate the 'source' element and 'destination' element, but the click is not made on the 'destination' element. (The Hover-over on 'source' element is done as expected and the 'destination' element gets displayed. The 'destination' element also gets highlighted, but WebDriver is not able to click the item)

```
public synchronized void mouseHoverOverMenuSelect(String SourceDisplayName, String DestinationDisplayName) {
    Actions builder = new Actions(ex.driver);
    WebElement source = getElement(SourceDisplayName);
    Action mouseHoverover = builder.moveToElement(source).build();    
    mouseHoverover.perform();
    WebElement destination = getElement(DestinationDisplayName);    
    mouseHoverover = builder.moveToElement(source).click(rm.element).release().build();    
    mouseHoverover.perform();
}
```

Selenium Standalone version: 2.31.0

IEDriverServer version: 2.25.2 to 2.32.3

Platform: Windows 7

IE Browser Version: 9.0.8112.16421

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML around the menu?

Comment: @Arran : The HTML around the Menu is provided below. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following elements were used in the above function:

```
WebElement source = xpath(.//*[@id='Support']/span/a)
WebElement destination = linkText(Education Center)
```

The HTML around the Menu is as follows:

```
<UL id=mainMenu class=nav sizcache="6" sizset="0">
    <LI id=Support onselectstart="return false;" onmouseover='setTimeout(function (){setBlocker("subMenuOfSupport")},10)' onmouseout=removeBlocker(); onmouseleave=removeBlocker(); onclick="javascript:activeMenu('Support');" ; valign="center" sizcache="6" sizset="12" jQuery1366868215713="18">
        <SPAN align="center" sizcache="6" sizset="12">
            <A onselectstart="return false;" onclick="showPage('Support');" target=contentMain>
                <P style="WIDTH: 59px">Support&nbsp;</P>
                <P class=down-arrow></P>
            </A>
        </SPAN>
        <UL style="Z-INDEX: 1000; MARGIN: 38px 0px 0px -77px; DISPLAY: none" id=subMenuOfSupport sizcache="6" sizset="13" jQuery1366868215713="5">
            <LI id="Education Center" onselectstart="return false;" class="last active" sizcache="6" sizset="13" jQuery1366868215713="19">
                <A style="HEIGHT: 10px" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="showSearchCriteria('Education Center','educationCenter','subMenuOfSupport');" target=contentMain>Education Center</A>
            </LI>
        </UL>
    </LI>
</UL>
```